# Angular 8 - Displaying components inside of other components

Tags: angular, typescript, components

**Problem:**

To display (custom) Navigation component (*titled topnav*) in *app.component.html*

**app.module.ts**

```
   import { TopnavComponent } from './topnav/topnav.component';

   @NgModule({
         declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            TopnavComponent,
         ]
    })
```

*edited to show AppComponent inside of declarations

**app.component.html**

```
 <topnav></topnav>
```

> **SOLUTION**
>
> ```
> <app-topnav></app-topnav>
> ```

**topnav.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-topnav',
  templateUrl: './topnav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topnav.component.css']
})
export class TopnavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

*edited to show topnav.component.ts

Not sure what I am missing here.  I attempted to try different directives, importing and exporting in different ways.  I know this is a basic idea behind Angular but having trouble and has been documented with Angular 2 but their solutions were not resolving in Angular 8.

Still getting this error:

```
1. If 'topnav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
  <div class="container">

   [ERROR ->]<topnav></topnav>

  </div>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@4:3
```

When adding to imports:[] in app.module.ts, from my understanding only takes modules based on the error I was getting.

Comment: where is the `AppComponent` inside your `declarations` array

Comment: I omitted when copying over the code - it is in there. Edit to show true code.

Comment: Can you show us the code for `topnav` component?

Comment: added topnav component. the HTML file within the component is for all purposes just a string that says 'test' right now.  I removed all other formatting to just get the component to show.

Comment: You are using the wrong selector. It should be `<app-topnav></app-topnav>` in `app.component.html`.

Comment: bingo! @ArchitGarg - Thank you I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong selector. Replace app.component.html with this:

```js
 <app-topnav></app-topnav>
```